# How to change all image src of WordPress site without changing database entries

Tags: wordpress

I am working with wordpress site..
I need to change all images srcs which are appearing on my site ...
I need to remove site url from image src and use another url instead of that...

Below thing is Must :
I do not want to update my database as i am working with HYPERDB and using multiple databases for my site...

Comment: If it is for content, then this filter should work: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: I tried using these filters preview_post_link,the_content and others which i have found from google..But do not know why they are not working in this site.. It may be because Hyperdb??

Comment: Hmm, here's how I thought it could work. Basically add your hook to `the_content`, then do a string replace of the url.

Comment: function my_the_content_filter($content) 
{
  $content = str_replace('http://localhost/nick/venues/','http://localhost/nick/vendors/',$content); 
  
  $content .= "This is test";
  return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );

Comment: I tried the above stuffs.. a simple stuff.... neither it replaces the url nor appending the text...

Comment: as a workaround u can try this http://jsfiddle.net/x9tknoc3/

Comment: your solution works , but i have made a changes to the javascript code... see my answer for the question ... Thanks @Dart for helping me

Comment: I think your str_replace syntax is off. Should be something like `str_replace($url, $new_url, $content);`. Glad you got it working though,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    i;

for(i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    var str = imgs[i].src;
    var res = str.replace('MY_SEARCH_URL', 'MY_REPLACE_URL');
    imgs[i].src = res;
}   
</script>
```

Here , replace MY_SEARCH_URL with your search string in image src.
and replace MY_REPLACE_URL with your replace string in image src.